# How to import javascript library in main.js for global availability throughout vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My `main.js` contains `import "mathjs";` and seems to be working fine within main.js as

```
console.log(median(5,4,6,1));
> 4.5
```

`median()` is however not available outside of main.js, i.e. in components. After reading [this answer](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-a-third-party-library-js-without-export-in-my-component/23047), I assumed that the simple import should be enough for global availability throughout the vue app?

Comment: You can import it wherever you need it, e.g in any script file, the bundler will do some treeshaking and only adds it to the built script once and only the methods you actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in main.js import all as `math` then add it as global property :

```
import * as math from 'mathjs'


const app=createApp({....})

app.config.globalProperties.$math =math
```

then in any component you could use it like `this.$math.theFunctionName`

Comment: Is this in the docs? Trying find the official way to include npm installed packages.

Comment: Yes, here the the link https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties

Answer (score 2):

In general when you are working with modern modules or a bundler like webpack, you have to import mathjs in every module (think file) you want to use it.

What is often done in the vue context, is adding the library to the Vue context itself with a plugin.

See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin

So this should be as easy as:

```js
const mathjsPlugin = {
  install(app){
    app.config.globalProperties.$mathjs = mathjs;
  }
}

const app = createApp(...);

app.use(mathjsPlugin);

// inside of a component
export default {
  created(){
    console.log(this.$mathjs....);
  }
}
```

I personally think explicitly importing is a cleaner approach, but if mathjs is used in most of the components, this approach can make sense